# CakePHP pre populate select box based on existing selection on related model

Tags: arrays, forms, cakephp, select

I am trying to pre-populate this State select box with the existing selection when editing records.
in a related model.

**plan_details/view.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->input('State',array('empty' => false,'options' => $state));
```

**plan_details_controller view function:**

```
$state = $this->PlanDetail->Plan->State->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('state', $state));
    debug($state);
```

**Array output in view.ctp** (as expected):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Oregon
    [2] => Washington
)
```

My select box above defaults to 1 in the array. I need it to default to the already existing selected value.

For example, when I added a record and a selected Washington(2), then when viewing my edit screen, the pre-selected value should be Washington with value 2.

I'm stuck and cracking at this for a while. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a page you need to set $this->data to auto populate it. Within your edit action

```
if (empty($this->data)) {
     $this->data = $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id);
}
```

This should read in the record then ( note the plural )

```
$states = $this->PlanDetail->Plan->State->find('list');
$this->set(compact('states'));
```

In your form it should read

```
echo $this->Form->input('Plan.state_id',array('empty' => false));
```

I find your approach a bit confusing but the above should work. Is this form for editing a Plan, PlanDetail or both

Comment: I will try this and let you know what happens. I am editing Plans on the PlanDetail view page. As you know, CakePHP naturally pulls in these types of relationship on bake (given your tables are correctly mapped), but I wanted to make the results editable. So for its fantastic just running into issues with select boxes values.

Comment: Hmmm.. The already selected state still does not show with those updates you suggested.

Comment: SO if you are editing Both you really need to set $this->data by
 
$this->data = $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id);

Is $this->data['Plan']['state_id'] populated?

Comment: $this->set(compact('states', $states)); is wrong, its either set(compact('states')) or set('states', $states) not both